# Duration of illegally terminated tenancy and right to occupancy

Tags: england-and-wales, tenancy-rules, eviction

Suppose one Is illegally Evicted from their home by an ignorant and zealous landlord. The tenant has some right to use reasonable force to reenter the property, criminal law act 1977 notwithstanding.

The extent, full nature and applicability of this right may be arguable but it does exist.

But what is its duration?

If the landlord has never taken any legal steps to terminate the tenancy then the tenant can use force to reenter an empty property the next day.

What about 48 months following the eviction though?

I’m guessing that some period within that time would be taken to imply that the tenancy is in fact, legally, over.

When does that transformation take place where the tenant no longer has any claim to enter or occupy the property?

Comment: Do you meann Criminal Law Act **1977**?

Comment: Under the Criminal Law Act 1977 (secs 6 & 7) forcible entry is prohibited unless the entrant has " lawful authority," or is "a displaced residential occupier or a protected intending occupier of the premises". Various provisions specify who is a "displaced residential occupier" (DRO). All of them seem to involve the DRO having been "excluded from occupation by one who entered those premises, ... as a trespasser" and meets other requirements. The status of DRO lasts as long as the person continues to be excluded by the same or another trespasser. [...]

Comment: [...] It is not clear to me that a landlord, even one doing an unlawful self-help eviction, would be "acting as a tresspasser", the act does not seem to define this phrase. See https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1977/45. The act does say that "he fact that a person has any interest in or right to possession or occupation of any premises shall not for the purposes of subsection (1) above constitute lawful authority for the use or threat of violence"

Comment: Yes, definitely did mean 1977. But I have definitely read that a landlord without rightful possession ie breaching a tenant’s right to quiet enjoyment is absolutely a trespasser.

Comment: Do you know if the doctrines of DRO and PIO were introduced through amendments to CLA1977 brought by LASPOA2012?

Comment: Section 6 (!A), which applied the concept of DRO and PIO was "inserted (3.2.1995) by 1994 c. 33, s. 72(2); S.I. 1995/127, art. 2(1), Sch.1." However, Section 12 (3) & 12 (4) which define FRO are apparently original. to the 1977 act. Section 12A which defines PIO was "inserted (3.2.1995) by 1994 c. 33, s. 74; S.I. 1995/127, art. 2(1), Sch. 1". So at least part of that concept was added in 1994/1995, but not in 2012. The web version linked to shows amendments and gives the dates and amending acts.

Comment: Does (!A) mean amended? Looks like you wrote FRO where you might have meant DRO.

Comment: What does the notation 3.2.1995 mean?

Comment: Is c. 33 chapter 33?

Comment: What is S.I. 1995/127?

Comment: Is there any nice guide or reference to this sort of notation?

Comment: "Section 6 (!A)" meant Section 6, sub-section (1A) (I made a typo.) I suspect that "3.2.1995" is a date, but i can't be sure.I suspect that "c. 33" means chapter 33 but i can't be sure. I fon't know what "S.I. 1995/127" means. I copied all these indications as they appear in the official web site. There is probably some guide or key to these notations, but I don't know where.

Comment: "Chapter" is the consecutive number for an Act in that year. SI is "Statutory Instrument" which is secondary legislation used to bring amendments made by Acts in to force when they are delayed or staggered over time. Therefore, as per the links at [footnote 1](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1977/45/section/6?timeline=false#reference-c4764441): Section 6(1A) was inserted by Section 73(2) of Criminal Justice and Public Order Act 1994, and came in to force on 03/02/1995  by virtue of the Criminal Justice and Public Order Act 1994 (Commencement No. 5 and Transitional Provisions) Order 1995.

Comment: From whence does the usage of chapter to mean sequential rank of statute within a given year originate?

Comment: What is meant by the term secondary legislation?

Comment: @JosephP. I've no idea when Chapter was first used, but see [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/79118/35069) for info on Secondary Legislation

Comment: @DavidSiegel it seems to me then that under the CLA1977 a DRO as an illegally evicted tenant who indeed has an interest in the property and a right to occupy it may legally use reasonable force (forcible entry) but not actual or threatened violence. Would you agree with that based upon your excerpts above?

Comment: On another note, I've seen and heard in numerous places that a landlord who has gained entry to a property that they might own but have let out to a tenant is absolutely trespassing. This makes sense because they have in letting out the property assigned to the tenant exclusive possession of it. Would you not agree?